# GitHub Action build up command for job output

Tags: bash, github

Need to execute this command in a GitHub Action

```
echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[\"Android\",\"iOS\"]}"
```

Need to build up the part which is `\"Android\",\"iOS\"` that could be any combination of targets.

But nothing works. I see that my variable is correct (a concatenated string) but it generates an error.

```
  echo "debugoutput:{\"targetPlatform\":[$stargets]}"
  echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[$stargets]}"
```

Context:

```
jobs:

  data:
    name: Prepare build info
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      build-matrix: ${{ steps.build-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Prepare build matrix
        id: build-matrix
        run: |
          echo "Create new target array"
          stargets=""
          if [  "${{ github.event.inputs.ios-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets="\\\"iOS\\\""
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.android-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == "" ]]; then
            stargets="\\\"Android\\\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.android-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets="${stargets},\\\"Android\\\""
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.pc-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == "" ]]; then
            stargets="\\\"StandaloneWindows64\\\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.pc-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets="${stargets},\\\"StandaloneWindows64\\\""
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.webgl-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == ""  ]]; then
            stargets="\\\"WebGL\\\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.webgl-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets="${stargets},\\\"WebGL\\\""
          fi      
          
          echo $stargets   
          echo "debugoutput:{\"targetPlatform\":[$stargets]}"
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[$stargets]}" # doesn't work
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[\"Android\",\"iOS\"]}" # works
```

I even tried the following but GHA is too stupid to be true. Nothing works trying to achieve a simple thing.

```
  echo $stargets > tmpfile
  echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[$(cat tmpfile)]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky but the following worked after some guessing. I still cannot do it in one action though. Need to pass the string to the next action as an environment variable which seems more like a trick than a clean solution.

```
jobs:

  data:
    name: Prepare build info
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      build-matrix: ${{ steps.build-matrix.outputs.matrix }}
    steps:
      - name: Prepare build matrix
        id: build-matrix-prep
        run: |
          echo "Create new target array"
          stargets=''
          if [  "${{ github.event.inputs.ios-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets='\"iOS\"'
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.android-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == '' ]]; then
            stargets="\"Android\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.android-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets=$stargets,'\"Android\"'
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.pc-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == '' ]]; then
            stargets="\"StandaloneWindows64\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.pc-required }}" == "true" ]; then
             stargets=$stargets,'\"StandaloneWindows64\"'
          fi
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.webgl-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == ''  ]]; then
            stargets="\"WebGL\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.webgl-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets=$stargets,'\"WebGL\"'
          fi      
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.macos-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == ''  ]]; then
            stargets="\"StandaloneWindows64\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.macos-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets=$stargets,'\"StandaloneOSX\"'
          fi  
          if [[  "${{ github.event.inputs.linux-required }}" == "true"  && $stargets == ''  ]]; then
            stargets="\"StandaloneLinux64\""
          elif [  "${{ github.event.inputs.linux-required }}" == "true" ]; then
            stargets=$stargets,'\"StandaloneLinux64\"'
          fi           
          echo $stargets   
          echo "action_trg=${stargets}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Use the value
        id: build-matrix
        run: |
          echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[${{ env.action_trg }}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable (`$stargets`) is inside a string (quoted). Hence, it won't get substituted.

Comment: So how can I succeed instead of just knowing what fails?

Comment: @NiklasR. Could you try enclosing it in curly braces. Like `${stargets}`

Comment: I tried everything. Nothing works. `echo "::set-output name=matrix::{\"targetPlatform\":[${stargets}]}"`

Comment: `Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: \.`

Comment: Why would a variable in double-quotes _not_ be substituted? Inside single-quotes, variable expansion is disabled, but not inside double-quotes as in the OPs code excerpt.

Comment: @AdminBee In this case it's sending a command to GitHub Action Runner. It's poorly documented. What worked in the end was to use single-quotes and set the value as an environment variable and then pick it up in a subsequent action. I don't know why. It worked though.

Comment: @AdminBee Maybe I should have used the double curly `${{ stargets }}`